# Cannot connect remotelly to a mariadb server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a mariadb server remotelly using terminal, but I get a little issue about that.

**Preconditions**

- I have connection to my remote server, and I can enter inside maria db using the next command 
  `mysql -u root -p****` and I enter without problems.
- Also I have commented this line of `my.conf` from the `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`.

When I'm trying to do this from my computer `mysql -u root -h mariadb.testing.des -p****` I get the following error in console

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'mariadb.testing.des' (using password: YES)
```

Why am I getting two different results using the same user? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help,

Jaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to ensure your server is reachable from remote. You also have to create a user which has privileges for the remote access to your desired schema. I strongly recommend not to create a remote root user with access to all. Best practice is to create a remote user for every single scheme.

In example: 
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'my.remote.host' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON jeffreys_db.* TO 'jeffrey'@'my.remote.host';

See also: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html